# How do the `DispatchResultWithPostInfo` and `Pays::No` actually work?

Tags: weight, fee

This makes me confused for a whole day.

---

First, please take a look at these:
[PolkadotApps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fdarwiniacrab-rpc.dwellir.com#/explorer/query/11305767), [Subscan](https://crab.subscan.io/extrinsic/11305767-1), [Code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/democracy/src/lib.rs#L1041).

From the code, we know this is a `Pays::No` call. Indeed, it doesn't cost any tx fee. But why the extrinsic detail shows:

```
{
  weight: 2,347,339,000
  class: Normal
  paysFee: Yes
}
```

IIUC, it should be:

```
PostDispatchInfo {
    actual_weight: None,
    pays_fee: Pays::No,
}
```

---

And the second weird thing, please take a look at these:
[PolkadotApps](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fdarwiniacrab-rpc.dwellir.com#/explorer/query/11436986), [Subscan](https://crab.subscan.io/extrinsic/11436986-1), [Code](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-bridges-common/blob/master/modules/grandpa/src/lib.rs#L201).

From the code, we know this is also a `Pays::No` call. But why does it cost a lot of tx fees? I've grabbed the data and tested it on the mock file. I'm sure `is_mandatory_header` is `true`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, I have an answer now.

[Code](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/src/weights.rs#L320-L327):

```
/// Calculate how much weight was actually spent by the `Dispatchable`.
pub fn calc_actual_weight(&self, info: &DispatchInfo) -> Weight {
    if let Some(actual_weight) = self.actual_weight {
        actual_weight.min(info.weight)
    } else {
        info.weight
    }
}
```

This is a `DispatchInfo` which was converted from `DispatchResultWithPostInfo`.

---

For the second question.

I found that the system will withdraw your balance then deposit it back.

So, it's free actually.

---

This answered my question. Because I'm on a quite old Substrate version.

If somebody comes from the future, also check @bkchr 's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that it show the correct information with no fees. There was actually some bug in reporting the correct result. It was fixed in the following commit (as of writing this, 6 days ago, so relative freshly fixed): https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/commit/7bb4936d788c84bfd9ed1bbde49336538459c5aa